# How to render a report including a Google visualization on a Joomla site to pdf

Tags: html, pdf, joomla, visualization

Ok, so I'm asking this to document my solution and will answer it myself but any improvements on my method are welcome.

The problem:
I need to render a report to both an html page embedded in an iframe (so it needs its own url) and to pdf.
The report includes an out of the ordinary graph which is not supported by any graph api I've seen.
My site uses the Joomla! CMS (V. 2.5.*) which means my backend is php and mysql.
I need the report to render without interference from the default template set on Joomla.
I'm running on a linux host, (basic LAMP).
Joomla uses the base tag in their html which screws up svg's url().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution involves the following: [wkhtml2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), js, [url parameters](http://www.marketingportland.com/marketing/joomla-articles/136-appending-onto-joomla-urls), and [writing a joomla component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Introduction).

I wrote a basic Joomla component with two site views, one that generated the report in html and one that displayed the report view in an iframe. So the report has a url to access it at, and I have a way to embed it. The component also had the js and css for generating the report extracted out to separate files for including in the media folder (but that was just for code cleanliness not functionality).

The report view had to do the following modifications to the page header to get the report to render right (save for the graph) otherwise the resources were loaded at the wrong times:

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setBase('');//base tag screws up svg urls so get rid of it
$document->addscript('http://www.google.com/jsapi');
$document->addscript(JURI::root(true).'/media/com_metahealthzone/javascript/chart.js');
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root(true).'/media/com_metahealthzone/css/chart.css');
```

The url used in the iframe had to have ?template=system appended, tmpl=component didn't work as the css from the template was still applied.

To get the Google visualization to look right I added javascript to the end of the `OnLoadCallback` to grab the svg and add a `linearGradient` as a child of the `defs` tag with `id="svg_grad"` (why Google doesn't support gradients, I don't know) then grab all the elements in the graph that needed the gradient and set their fill to `'url(#svg_grad)'`. Remember to use `setAttributeNS` because of the svg namespace, and make the gradient `stop` tags be children of the gradient not of defs.

I still have to do the tweaks for VML (stupid IE).

There were some issues with wkhtml2pdf that I had to overcome too. When you add an element to the DOM using js it doesn't behave like other browsers. You must keep the returned handle because you can't get the new element using `document.getElement*` type functions. Also you have to instruct wkhtml2pdf to wait for the js to run using `--no-stop-slow-scripts` or the graph won't show up (it's slow). I also had to impersonate the user's session by setting the cookie for wkhtml2pdf using the `--cookie <name> <value>` argument.